# How to add a parallel edge to a Graph?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

```
typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS,allow_parallel_edge_tag,edgeWeightProperty> UGraph;
UGraph ug(n);
add_edge(0,1,ug);
add_edge(0,1,ug);
```

only one edge can be drawn in the graph "ug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjacency_matrix does not support the concept of parallel edges. Your usage of `allow_parallel_edge_tag` does not make the matrix to behave differently. It simply assigns `allow_parallel_edge_tag` as a vertex property, and Boost essentially ignore this property.

If you need parallel edges you should use adjacency_list instead.